# How to rename files recursively with Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a bash script that should replace any occurrence of a given `pattern` with an other, given, `expression` in any path in a given directory. For instance, if I have the following tree structure:

```
.
|- file1
|- file-pattern-pattern.html
|- directory-pattern/
|  |- another-pattern
|  \- pattern.pattern
\- other-pattern/
   \- a-file-pattern
```

it should end up looking like

```
.
|- file1
|- file-expression-expression.html
|- directory-expression/
|  |- another-expression
|  \- expression.expression
\- other-expression/
   \- a-file-expression
```

The main issue I have is that most solution I have found make either usage of the `**` glob pattern alongside with a `shopt -s globstar nullglob` or `find` to execute `rename` on all the files, but since I actually change the name of a directory during that operation, it breaks with messages like `find: ./directory-pattern: No such file or directory` or `rename: ./directory-pattern/another-expression: not accessible: No such file or directory`.

The second issue is that, according to `rename`'a man page, it "will rename the specified files by repalcing the first occurrence" of the pattern, not *all* occurrences, and I didn't find any option to overwrite this behavior. Of course, I don't want to "just run `rename` with `-v` until it doesn't spit anything anymore", which just sounds silly.

So the question is: how do I achieve that bulk-renaming in Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: leave only the 1-pass solution that apparently works as well as the 2-passes.

You'll probably have to explore the hierarchy depth first. Example with `find` and a `bash` exec script:

```bash
$ find . -depth -name '*pattern*' -exec bash -c \
  'f=$(basename "$1"); d=$(dirname "$1"); \
   mv "$1" "$d/${f//pattern/expression}"' _ {} \;
```

Demo:

```bash
$ tree .
.
├── file-pattern-pattern.html
├── file1
├── foo-pattern
│   └── directory-pattern
│       ├── another-pattern
│       └── pattern.pattern
└── other-pattern
    └── a-file-pattern

$ find . -depth -name '*pattern*' -exec bash -c \
  'f=$(basename "$1"); d=$(dirname "$1"); \
   mv "$1" "$d/${f//pattern/expression}"' _ {} \;

$ tree .
.
├── file-expression-expression.html
├── file1
├── foo-expression
│   └── directory-expression
│       ├── another-expression
│       └── expression.expression
└── other-expression
    └── a-file-expression
```

Explanation: `-depth` tells `find` to *process each directory's contents before the directory itself*. This avoids one of the issues you encountered when referring to a directory that was already renamed. The `bash` script uses simple pattern substitutions to replace all occurrences of string `pattern` by string `expression`.

Comment: Works like a charm! I understand why you need to do this making a depth-first search (although I didn't know that option even existed), but I don't understand why you should replace files after directories. After all, if I visit a file in find's search tree before its parent directory, it's fine too, isn't it?

Comment: You're right, one pass only should be sufficient if it is depth first but I could not prove it yet (I am struggling with symbolic links), so I preferred to suggest a solution I am reasonably confident with. But you can give it a try, Use only the first command and remove the `-type d`.

Comment: A single pass works fine too on the few tests I did. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I convinced myself that a single pass should work at least as well as two. I edit my answer accordingly.